# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ userId: '5c48a95df9bd9a33c0ff9405'

Tags: typescript

'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ userId: \'5c48a95df9bd9a33c0ff9405\',\n  username: \'ahsan\',\n  iat: 1549024353,\n  exp: 1549110753 }" at path "user" for model "Rental"'

```
router.get("/manage", UserControl.loginMiddleware, (req, res) => {
const user = res.locals.user;
Rental.where({ user })
.populate("bookings")
.exec((err, foundRentals) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(422).send({ errors: mongoErrors(err.errors) });
  }
  return res.json(foundRentals);
  });
});
```

Comment: this is complete get request code i want all rental and booking data of login user only but it show cast error when i console err

Comment: What's the content of `foundRentals` when you log it to your console? And what's the structure of `Rental`?

Comment: foundRental is just argument i pass it as an argument

Comment: then what is this line for? `return res.json(foundRentals);` It actually says 'return foundRentals as JSON'.

Comment: see when i use Rental.where(user.userId) this is run correctly for all user data

Comment: it get all the data on Rental collection in Rental User and bookings is present

Comment: @Lynx242 i found my answer thankyou for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get("/manage", UserControl.loginMiddleware, (req, res) => {
const user = res.locals.user;
Rental.where("user",user.userId)
.populate("bookings")
.exec((err, foundRentals) => {
  if (err) {
  return res.status(422).send({ errors: mongoErrors(err.errors) });
     }
 return res.json(foundRentals);
   });
});
```